# JavaScript graph from time and data

Tags: javascript, graph

I have array of objects, they contain unix timestamp and some data. For example:

```
[{ time: 1496709642, data: 35.5 }, { time: 1499709642, data: 36.2 }]
```

Data is not evenly distributed, so for example after 1499709642 can come 1499709645, 1499908442 and so. What library can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a time series graph

Here is the jsfiddle using high charts time series

You can find a jsfiddle using highcharts time series the moment you search on google or through the following link

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series